# The convenient approach to a calculus problem in two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, education

A student came to me with the following problem.

> Construct a function $g \colon {\Bbb R}\to {\Bbb R}$ such that the function $f \colon {\Bbb R}^2 \to {\Bbb R}$ defined by $$ f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{e^{x^2}-e^{y^2}}{x-y} &\text{if $x \neq y$} \\ g(x) &\text{if $x=y$} \end{cases} $$ is continuous. Is the function $f$ differentiable at the origin?

It is immediate to find the unique $g$ that *could* solve the problem. However, the student was in trouble since he was unable to check that this function $g$ was an actual solution. The computation of $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,x_0)} \frac{e^{x^2}-e^{y^2}}{x-y}$$ is intuitive, but the student could not prove rigorously his conjecture. The same for the limit $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\nabla f(0,0)\cdot (x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$

I suggested the use of some Taylor expansion of the exponential around zero, but I wonder if there is some straightforward approach. Actually, the definition of $f$ is given as a "incremental ratio" of a smooth function, and I guess there is a general result about the extension of the incremental ratio to the diagonal of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: For some, the Taylor series of the exponential function **is** the definition. You may find a slightly more elegant method using a different characterisation of the exponential function, but (and not to split hairs here) it's pretty much impossible to find something more straightforward, if you define the exponential function this way. Even then, doing it with the Taylor series is pretty to-the-point as it is, so that's a fairly high bar for an alternative proof to clear in terms of elegance.

Comment: I suppose that $g(x)=2xe^{x^2}$?

Comment: @Siminore Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

For the first part in order to make things simpler, fixed $y=x_0$, we can refer to the limit of a single variable

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{ e^{x^2}-e^{x_0^2} }{x-x_0}$$

which by definition of derivative for $h(x)=e^{x^2}$ leads to $g(x)=h'(x)=2xe^{x^2}$.

For the second part, that is

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\nabla f(0,0)\cdot (x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ e^{x^2}-e^{y^2}-(x^2-y^2) }{(x-y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

to avoid Taylor's expansion we can use that

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{e^t-1-t}{\frac{t^2}2}=1$$

which can be easily shown by l'Hospital and therefore

$$\frac{ e^{x^2}-e^{y^2}-(x^2-y^2) }{(x-y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=$$
$$=\frac{ e^{x^2}-1-x^2 }{\frac{x^4}2 }
\frac{ \frac{x^4}2  }{(x-y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
-\frac{ e^{y^2}-1-y^2 }{\frac{y^4}2 }\frac{ \frac{y^4}2  }{(x-y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\to1\cdot 0-1\cdot 0=0$$

Comment: Yes, this is the easiest part of the problem. The major difficulty for my student is to check the the multivariable limit describing continuity is actually your $g$.

Comment: @Siminore Isn't it sufficient to obtain that by the definition of derivative. Why would we check it further?

Comment: It seems to me that the gradient of $f$ at the origin is $(1,1)$. Well, actually we are computing the limit of the incremental ratio with two moving variables. This is not the definition of the derivative at a given point...

Comment: @Siminore Ops yes of course, I didn't check it in detail and we have  $$f_x(0,0)=\lim{x\to 0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=\lim{x\to 0} \frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}=1$$ I fix that part. Thanks